# Is this an object or function or something else?

Tags: javascript, object

I have been researching objects and functions and cannot figure out what the code below is. I have looked at all the declaration types I can find for objects and cannot find one that looks like this. Here is the code:

```
new Maplace({
        locations: SampleLocations,
        map_div: '.gmap-container',
        name: 'Map'
    });
```

The closest I have seen is this:

```
var person = new Object();
```

In the end I am trying to edit one of the object properties (if that is what it is). So for example, I would like to updated `locations` later in my script.

If this is a function, I haven't seen a function with key:value pairs before. If this is an object, why do I always log an error when I try this:

```
console.log(Maplace.name);
```

I got this code while using this plugin (maplacejs.com). I looked through their script and (because I'm fairly new to JS) I cannot figure out how to update one of the object properties. Yet in their setup doc that is how you create a new instance of the Maplace object.

Comment: That's declaring a new instance of the class `Maplace` whose constructor is apparently accepting an object as argument.

Comment: The -1 means that someone down voted your question. See how it works here http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation

Comment: The question was clear enough for me to answer his question and get his code working.

Comment: I do find it ironic though that some people care more about rules than learning. Last time I checked this site was made for helping others learn and sharing knowledge. I bet someone will come across my "unclear" question and learn from it, as I did. Of course neither of you care about that, too busy reading the rulebook, aha.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is creating a new object by calling a constructor function. The single parameter to the constructor function is an object. The code below does the same thing:

```
var myObject = {
  locations: SampleLocations,
  map_div: '.gmap-container',
  name: 'Map'
};

new Maplace(myObject);
```

Hopefully making the two steps explicit makes it clearer for you.

But the code above is a little strange, for one reason. When you use the `new` keyword it creates a new object. And the code above does not store that object, it seemingly throws away the object. Or possibly the code in `Maplace` is doing something unexpected like creating a global variable or or some other side effects. Usually you would store the new object in a variable:

```
var myMaPlace = new Maplace(myObject);
```

As I suspected, and upon [reading the docs](https://maplacejs.com/) and [looking at the code](https://github.com/danielemoraschi/maplace.js/blob/master/src/maplace.js), the examples all either use a variable to store the new object *or* invoke the `Load` method immediately to attach the map to an html element and display the map immediately. In which case, the object is "thrown out", but since the map is already displayed that might ok.

Also, according to the docs, you can change the options using the `Load` method, so I would imagine something like this would work (not tested):

```
var myMap = new Maplace({
  locations: SampleLocations,
  map_div: '.gmap-container',
  name: 'Map'
}).Load();

// Later
myMap.Load({ locations: newLocations });
```

Comment: Yes this did help a lot, thank you!

Comment: This is why I get confused: I re-read the JS doc (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects#Using_a_constructor_function) again, but nothing starts with new. It is ALWAYS starts with var.

Comment: I expanded my answer with more details about `new`. The code you posted does indeed seem strange.

Comment: I didn't think it was necessary at the time but I think it is now. I got this code while using this plugin (https://maplacejs.com/). I looked through their script and (because I'm fairly new to JS) I cannot figure out how to update one of the object properties. Yet in their setup doc that is how you create a new instance of the Maplace object. Which is fine, but then how do I later update that? I am going for something like this:                                                         if ($(window).width() > 600 && $(window).width() < 769) {
Maplace.name = 'NewMapName'
  } Hmm...

Comment: See updated answer.

Comment: Thank you, thank you, thank you! I saw "Loads or updates the current configuration and constructs the map" But I could not figure out how to actually utilize that. It seems it may actually be simpler than I thought! Ugh. Thank you again for your time and effort, I really do appreciate it and maybe this can help someone else!

Comment: If it does work, please accept my answer ;-)

Comment: That absolutely did it! I saved the object to a var - `var myMap = new Maplace();` and then used `myMap.Load({...})` to update the Maplace object properties based on the window width. You rock!